# kendo chart: sort stacked bar on each category

Tags: kendo-ui, stacked-chart

I want to sort the bar series on each category of my kendo chart [Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syave.png).

My code is here https://dojo.telerik.com/EDERUfEY

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only sorting that we can apply is on the data source group.

```
"dataSource": {
          data: data,
          group: {
            field: "type",
            dir: "desc"
          },
          sort: {
            field: "daysOut",
            dir: "asc"
          },
```

This [API Reference Link](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/sorting/sort-stacked-series-groups), explains why data source sort attribute is overridden by grouping and how we can see it sorted by a particular group when we click on the legend labels.
As of now, I have not found any solutions to render the chart with a stacked bar sorted by values.

Comment: Hello Marissa, The sort in the kendo support is for complete columns. I need sort the bar series in each column.

Comment: Hi @Enzoff, I have updated the link above, do check it out.

Comment: Hi Marissa, I see the sample but it does not sort series in each columns. All columns begin with serie "A". In the kendo sample if one category (for exaple "Adam") if the serie "A" set to a value greather than serie "B", it still  draw serie "A" before than series "B"